# Rotate to face vector in Houdini with python

Tags: python, vector, rotation, houdini

I am trying to make a geometry in Houdini face the same direction as a normal on a line. I am getting the normal as a vector with magnitude 1 and then using the formula angle = arccos((x dot y)/(magnitude x * magnitude y). to get the angle to rotate the object and then multiplying by 180 to convert it to degrees. for some reason this does not give a consistent result.

Am I doing something obviously wrong with my math? I am new to Houdini so I'm not sure if I might be missing something about the environment that would complicate this.

Here is the python code I am using.

```py
#normalize and store as vector3
currentNormal = hou.Vector3(currentNormal).normalized()
previousNormal = hou.Vector3(previousNormal).normalized()

#get dot product and magnitudes
dotProd = numpy.dot(previousNormal, currentNormal)
previousMagnitude = numpy.sqrt((previousNormal[0]**2) + (previousNormal[1]**2) + (previousNormal[2]**2))
currentMagnitude = numpy.sqrt((currentNormal[0]**2) + (currentNormal[1]**2) + (currentNormal[2]**2))

nextLocationRotate = numpy.arccos(dotProd/(previousMagnitude * currentMagnitude))

nextLocationRotate = [0.0, nextLocationRotate*180, 0.0]
```

I am trying to get a rotation around the y axis.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without more information. Are your normals orthogonal to the y-axis? Are you able to host a simple hip file demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @ahfx The normals are not strictly orthogonal to the Y axis, no. This will need to work for any line in 3D space so the normals could potentially be not orthogonal. The points I am testing with so far have been orthogonal but ultimately I will need to have it work even if they are not. I'll try to setup a .hip file that shows what I have.

Comment: @ahfx Here is a [.hip file with my code](https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/798254/BasicLineFollowingExample.hip). If you move the timeline you can see how the motion is working. currently it is only rotating around the y axis and all normals are orthogonal to y but eventually I intend to have it follow a line in all 3 dimensions and rotate horizontally and vertically. The code above is in the "TrafficSim" network in the python node named "lane1"